# Rails: find_or_create relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

My field `member_id` is empty if I create a new exercise for a workout.

workout.rb

```
     belongs_to :member
     has_and_belongs_to_many :exercises

     def add_exercise_with_name(exercise_name)
        self.exercises << Exercise.find_or_create_by(name: exercise_name)
      end
```

exercise.erb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :workouts
belongs_to :member
```

exercise_controller.erb

```
def create
    @workout = current_user.workouts.find(params[:workout_id])
    @exercise = @workout.add_exercise_with_name(exercises_params['name'])
    redirect_to workout_path(@workout)
end
```

How could i add the member for the exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the id as an extra parameter to the method.

```
def add_exercise_with_name(exercise_name, member_id)
  self.exercises << Exercise.find_or_create_by(name: exercise_name, member_id: member_id)
end
```

This has a side effect. Now the `find_or_create` call will consider the `member_id` when looking up the Exercise. If this is not desirable, use [`create_with(member_id: member_id)`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).

```
self.exercises << Exercise.create_with(member_id: member_id).find_or_create_by(name: exercise_name)
```

Furthermore, you can use block syntax:

```
  self.exercises << Exercise.find_or_create_by(name: exercise_name) do |exercise|
    exercise.member_id = member_id
  end
```

Comment: This answer is probably better because of the pointed-out caveat.

Comment: So if exercise belongs_to member and i will do `find_or_create_by(name: exercise_name)` it will use the exercises with the same name but maybe different "owner"/member ?

Comment: @orgertot yes. If you include the `member_id` in the `find_or_create_by`, then the query `where` clause will contain both conditions `where name = 'foo' AND member_id = 1`. This may or may not be what you want depending on how you want to design your system.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your `Workout` model:

```
def add_exercise_with_name(exercise_name, member)
  self.exercises << Exercise.find_or_create_by(name: exercise_name, member: member)
end
```

Then pass in the member in your controller:

```
member = Member.find_by whatever_column: 'value'
@exercise = @workout.add_exercise_with_name(exercises_params['name'], member)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow associations, then foreign keys populate automatically.
In controllers you can also use ActiveRecord requests through associations:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts
  has_many :exercises, through: :workouts
end


class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_and_belongs_to_many :exercises
end


class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workouts
end


class ExercisesController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :get_workout

  def create
    @workout.exercises.where(name: exercises_params['name']).first_or_create
    redirect_to workout_path(@workout)
  end

  private

  def get_workout
    @workout = current_user.workouts.find(params[:workout_id])
  end
end
```